# What does nibNameOrNil really mean?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

The default `init` method signature on XCode-generated view controllers is:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{ }
```

I've seen these initialized with both values supplied, just the nib name (with bundle as nil), or just `nil` as both.  All seem to work.

How does the UIViewController really handle  `self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];`?  Is there a disadvantage to just passing in `nil` for both values?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you pass `nil` as the nibName, the method will look for a nib with the same filename as your view controller.

For instance, if you have a view controller called `MyViewController` it will look for a `MyViewController.xib` nib file.

If no nib is found, you will need to override the `loadView` method to create and assign a UIView to the controller's view outlet.

```
- (void)loadView
{
    UIView *theView = [[UIView alloc] ...
    // Setup the main view
    self.view = theView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName%3abundle%3a):

nibName:

> If you specify nil for the nibName parameter and you do not override the loadView method, the view controller searches for a nib file using other means. See nibName.

nibBundle:

> The bundle in which to search for the nib file. This method looks for the nib file in the bundle's language-specific project directories first, followed by the Resources directory. If nil, this method looks for the nib file in the main bundle.